# scores api is not working

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, facebook-unity-sdk

Im developing a mobile game, when I call the FB.Api to post a screenshot via

```
((FB.API("me/photos", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, Callback, wwwForm);))
```

which works fine, but then I tried to call the Score api via

```
((FB.API ("/me/scores", HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);))
```

and nothing happens. My app is in development mode in the Facebook dashboard.

Am I doing something wrong or my app needs to be approved? I'm testing on an iPhone.

Comment: What does nothing happens mean? The app freezes when you call that API and nothing happens?

Comment: freezes a little bit and then continues normally, but nothing happens on my Facebook timeline.

Comment: Not all scores are published on the timeline. Look in the activity log and see if it is there. If it is then everything is working

Comment: no, there is nothing in my activity log :/

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
((FB.API ("/me/scores", Facebook.HttpMethod.POST, LogCallback, scoreData);))
```